# MySQL - Find what other actors an actor has worked together

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not sure how to explain this question in a title so I will give you an example with movies and actors.

I have three tables (table name - fields):

```
actor - id, name
movie - id, title
actor_movie - actor_id, movie_id
```

I want to create a query that uses an actor.id in the WHERE clause and the output should be a list of actors who has worked on movies with this actor. Preferably ordered by how many movies they worked together on.

Edit: This is what I got now but it does not display the the other actors. It only count how many movies actor 157 has been in:

```
SELECT a.name, COUNT(m.title) movie_count
FROM actor_movie
JOIN actor
ON actor.id = actor_movie.actor_id
WHERE actor.id = 157
GROUP BY actor.name
ORDER BY movie_count DESC
```

Comment: What seems to be a problem? Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: To be honest I am not sure where to start other than the very basic SELECT. Your comment suggests that there is an easy solution. :)

Comment: Start learning. You will need `JOIN`, `COUNT`, `GROUP BY`

Comment: @PM77-1 I am sorry, I am not that new to MySQL even though my comment suggested that. I have added the basic query I have worked on in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select movies with the actor, select other actors in the movies, group by actor and count.

```
select a.id, a.name, count(*)
from actor a
join actor_movie am on am.actor_id = a.id
where movie_id in (select movie_id from actor_movie where actor_id = @actor) 
and actor_id <> @actor -- remove this if you want to see how many movies the @actor has
group by a.id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Another way to write this:

```
select a.id, a.name, counted.movies
from actor a
join 
(
  select actor_id, count(*) as movies
  from actor_movie
  where movie_id in (select movie_id from actor_movie where actor_id = @actor) 
  and actor_id <> @actor -- remove this if you want to see how many movies the @actor has
  group by actor_id
) counted on counted.actor_id = a.id
order by count(*) desc;
```

And yet another:

```
select 
  actor_id, 
  (select name from actor a where a.id = am.actor_id) as name,
  count(*) as movies
from actor_movie am
where movie_id in (select movie_id from actor_movie where actor_id = @actor) 
and actor_id <> @actor -- remove this if you want to see how many movies the @actor has
group by actor_id
order by count(*) desc;
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I assumed I needed a subquery but I have not used it so much in the WHERE clause. `actor_id <> @actor` was a very nice touch!

Do you have any suggestion to how I can change the title of the question to be more descriptive?

Comment: You are welcome. The title fits your question perfectly. Don't change it.